# How to use UnsafeMutableRawPointer in Kotlin/Native?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am trying to implement an observer to the changes of UserDefaults for a given key in iOS part of Multi-platform library written with Kotlin/Native. The Swift signature of the function that I need to implement is:

```swift
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

But it seem that there is no mapping on Kotlin/Native side for `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`.

How can I achieve that? The code swift code that I would like to port to Kotlin is the following:

```swift
let globalDataStore = UserDefaults(suiteName: "global")

func setObserver() {
    globalDataStore?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "StringKey", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print("observeValue: \(change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] ?? "NO VLAUE")");
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is your work flow, it's not clear? What part would is intended to call this method and what part to implement?

Comment: I updated the question with the entire swift code that I would like to port to Kotlin/Native. I hope that clarifies what I want to achieve.

Comment: Do you really need to pass UnsafeMutableRawPointer into kotlin code? Probably it'll be enough to implement some oberver logic (function or class) in kotlin part and in swift part just call this logic from `observeValue` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I found in the documentation, the Objective-C version of the `observeValue` method utilizes `void *` typed argument as a `context`. This type is being mapped to Kotlin/Native as a `COpaquePointer`(see [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html#using-bindings) doc's **Pointer types** subsection). There is no `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` representation as K/N currently provides interoperability with the Objective-C only.